# Migration options?

Tags: discussion, migration

When I voted to close something because I thought it fit better on Freelancers.stackexchange, I only had options to migrate it to English or ELL -- how does one propose other places to migrate to?

(I would suggest options include Freelancers, Workplace, and Interpersonal Questions, just based on ones I've seen today.)  Thanks.

Comment: This is very, very close to a duplicate of [ELL vs. ELU - where to send your beginner Engish questions](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1615/2533), except that this is about a different site. The reasoning in [my answer](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1616/2533) should apply equally well, though.

Answer (score 4):

In order to have other migration paths, we need to graduate. Related: [Writing.SE clamours for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781/386257)

What you can do in the meantime is flag the question, and under "in need of moderator intervention" write where you think the question should go. It takes time - we only have three moderators, and they're not on 24/7, but eventually they get to it.

Comment: Something that helps us evaluate flags like these is if you can show us you've done the initial investigation -- checked their on-topic list, or you're an experienced user there, or something like that.  Sometimes a question *sounds* like it fits another site but they'd just close it, which makes a really confusing experience for the person who asked the question.  So we need to check, unless we know you have already.  Thanks!